# Is The Co-finite Topology is of Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If we consider the co-finite topology $$\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup \{\Omega\subset E, card(E\setminus \Omega)<+\infty\}$$

where $E$ is an infinite set

How to know if $(E,\tau)$ is a Hausdorff space?

Edit:

If i suppose that it is a Hausdorff space then for each point $x,y\in E$ there exists two open sets $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ such that  $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2=\emptyset$

As $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are opens the intersection is also open, that is $card(E\setminus(\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2))<\infty$

but we suppose that $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2=\emptyset$ then $$ card(E\setminus(\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2))=card(E)=+\infty$$

contradiction.

Thank you

Comment: Hint:  Try to prove that (assuming $E$ is infinite) that any two non-empty open sets must intersect.

Comment: if i suppose that $\Omega_1$ is an open containing $x$ and $\Omega_2$ is an open containig $y$,  and $\Omega_1\cap \Omega_2=\emptyset$ this impossible because $+\infty>card(E\setminus(\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2)=card(E)=+\infty$ like this ? @JasonDeVito

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove that the intersection of two nonempty open sets is nonempty.

Indeed, if $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are nonempty open sets, then, using $A^c=E\setminus A$ for $A\subseteq E$ and the fact that $\Omega_1^c$ and $\Omega_2^c$ are finite,
$$
\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2=((\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2)^c)^c=
(\Omega_1^c\cup\Omega_2^c)^c
$$
is the complement of a finite subset of $E$, hence infinite, in particular not empty.

Comment: where is the error in my proof ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Not wrong, *per se*, but too complicated and improvable.